# Parse json array and loop through all the data for Pivot.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array data in this format:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_1",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 40,
        "rejected": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_2",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 30,
        "rejected": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_3",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 13,
        "rejected": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_4",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 13,
        "rejected": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "job_id": "some_id",
  "total_jobs": 60
}
```

where I just need to access the `jobs` object and grab `id` and `status` and all info for `job_fields` and `stats` (or all info for now).

```
  // example is from here
  // https://pivottable.js.org/examples/mps.html
  $(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(mps) {
        $("#output").pivotUI(mps);
    });
 });
```

the example works with this json format:

```
[{
    "Province": "Quebec",
    "Party": "NDP",
    "Age": 22,
    "Name": "Liu, Laurin",
    "Gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Province": "Quebec",
    "Party": "Bloc Quebecois",
    "Age": 43,
    "Name": "Mourani, Maria",
    "Gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Province": "Ontario",
    "Party": "Conservative",
    "Age": "",
    "Name": "O'Toole, Erin",
    "Gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

I am not sure how to modify the javascript so it can read my json format. I can't modify the json format to match the above format, so in the above javascript example, `province, party, etc` are all passed to the function.

I want to do the same but with my json format, so output `id, status, all members of job_fields (ex: TITLE, etc. ), all members of stats (ex: applied, rejected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` and use `Object.assign` and `spread operator` to make an object

```js
var obj={"jobs":[{"id":"some_random_id_1","email":"some@email.com","email_type":"html","status":"pending","job_fields":{"TITLE":"job title here"},"stats":{"applied":40,"rejected":20}},{"id":"some_random_id_2","email":"some@email.com","email_type":"html","status":"pending","job_fields":{"TITLE":"job title here"},"stats":{"applied":30,"rejected":20}},{"id":"some_random_id_3","email":"some@email.com","email_type":"html","status":"pending","job_fields":{"TITLE":"job title here"},"stats":{"applied":13,"rejected":1}},{"id":"some_random_id_4","email":"some@email.com","email_type":"html","status":"pending","job_fields":{"TITLE":"job title here"},"stats":{"applied":13,"rejected":1}}],"job_id":"some_id","total_jobs":60}

var result = obj.jobs.map(({id,status,job_fields,stats}) => {
  return Object.assign({}, {id}, {status}, {...job_fields}, {...stats});
});

console.log(result);
```

Or you can make it shorter like:

```
var result = obj.jobs.map( ({id,status,job_fields,stats}) => Object.assign({},{id},{status},{...job_fields},{...stats}) );
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all jobs have job_fields.TITLE, stats.applied and stats.rejected maybe the following will do:

```js
const json = {
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_1",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 40,
        "rejected": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_2",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 30,
        "rejected": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_3",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 13,
        "rejected": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "some_random_id_4",
      "email": "some@email.com",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "pending",
      "job_fields": {
        "TITLE": "job title here"
      },
      "stats": {
        "applied": 13,
        "rejected": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "job_id": "some_id",
  "total_jobs": 60
};

console.log(
  json.jobs.map(
    (job)=>({
      id:job.id,
      status:job.status,
      title:job.job_fields.TITLE,
      applied:job.stats.applied,
      rejected:job.stats.rejected
    })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with below snippet:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON("data.json", function(orgData) {
    var pivotData = [];
    orgData.jobs.forEach(function (job, ind) {
        var reqInfo = {};
        reqInfo['id'] = job.id;
        reqInfo['status'] = job.status;
        reqInfo['jobTitle'] = job.job_fields && job.job_fields.TITLE;
        reqInfo['applied'] = job.stats && job.stats.applied;
        reqInfo['rejected'] = job.stats && job.stats.rejected;
        pivotData.push(reqInfo)
    })
    $("#output").pivotUI(pivotData);
});
```

});

Comment: this works great thank you :) is it possible to dynamically populate the info assuming we dont know how many members `stats` has? for example what if stats has more members, similar to `job_fields` where some jobs have different job fields not just the title

Comment: Yes u can do it. Loop through job.stats and assign its property to reqInfo. If your using ES6, you can use spread operator on job.stats

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#output").pivotUI(mps.jobs);
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you edit your answer to add some context. You can read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to write better answer.